# How to add a Accordion to your React Project via Material Ui design?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to implement an accordion in my react project via  material Ui design.But some how to expand feature of the accordion just dosent seem to work. When I tried implementing it.I get the follow error on the broswer

./src/components/About.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore' in '/Users/arundhati/Development/code/Mod5/capstone/client/src/components'

About.js

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Cont } from "../Cont";
import "./stylingfolder/Intro.css";


import * as React from 'react';
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';


function About(){
    const {user}=useContext(Cont)
    return(
        <>
        <h1 className="welcome">Welcome {user.name} </h1>
        <div>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion disabled>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3a-content"
          id="panel3a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Disabled Accordion</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default About;
```

Comment: I think you dont have installed icons. Try _npm install @mui/icons-material_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem** is that mui icons is not part of general mui package.

**Solution** is to install mui icons

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

or

```
yarn add @mui/icons-material
```